# Setting the font of the LaTeX mathematical notation elements in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

[Bokeh allows for text elements with LaTeX mathematical notation formatting](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.0/docs/user_guide/styling/mathtext.html). However, once a string has been processed with the math formatting, the font becomes a Times-like font. The default font for the rest of Bokeh is Helvetica. I would like to make the fonts in my figure be consistent, regardless of whether it is a font that had the LaTeX math formatting processed or not. Within the [LaTeX formatting section of the Bokeh documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.0/docs/user_guide/styling/mathtext.html#latex), it's noted that

> You can use some of Bokeh’s standard text properties to change the appearance of rendered math text.

with the examples appending the text property name to the end of the element (e.g. `figure.xaxis.axis_label_text_color` for the text color). Unfortunately, using `figure.xaxis.axis_label_text_font` does not seem to work.

Is there a way to set the font for the LaTeX elements of the figure? Or even a way to change the global LaTeX engine's (seemingly mathjax) font so that I can get the fonts to match?

**Example showing the differing font:**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure as Figure
from bokeh.io import show

figure = Figure(x_axis_label=r'$$\text{Different font with math formatting }M_{2}^{3}$$',
                y_axis_label=r'Normal bokeh font', width=400, height=400)
figure.line(x=[0, 1, 2, 3], y=[4, 6, 5, 7])
show(figure)
```

[image]